# Firefox change tab title

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, title-bar

I would like to change tab title for specific site like facebook.com to some custom text. The reason why is because I don't want to see notification(s) count in the tab title, while I am browsing other sites (in other tabs).
There is good extension for this for Chrome called Tab Modifier. How can I do this in Firefox?
(For current workaround I use pinned tab).

Comment: It's possible the [Rename Tab Title](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rename-tab-title/) could help.  I haven't tried it out myself, though.

Answer (score 8):

[Tab retitle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-retitle/)
is the only FF addon I found to rename rewriting pages.  You can assign a custom shortcut.  Will only rename the active tab.

1. You can rename the tab itself with the option to display the current page name as well as the custom text.
2. You can separately rename "exact match" the URL (including # page positions) so that whenever that url is loaded in any tab your custom title is applied.
3. If you bookmark a retitled tab, FF saves the custom title as the bookmark name.  The Tab Retitle dialog box then shows the bookmark name as an option. 1 click to re-apply it if all else fails.

A combination of both seems to work - tab name 1st, exact match second.  Persistent between sessions.

It also has regex facility although I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 5):

A bit cumbersome but doesn't need any extensions added: F12, Console, and enter `document.title='my tab title'`

Comment: I love this <3 A bit ironic that the latest answer (at the time of commenting) quotes a solution that has existed in browsers long before the question was even asked!

Answer (score 3):

I have not yet found a "Tab Modifier for Firefox". That regex URL Matcher is fantastic!

In Firefox I use Tab Mix Plus, which sadly, is not automatic. You must right-click on the tab, then select 'Rename' from the menu. To activate the tab renaming function, select Tools > Tab Mix Options > Menu > Tab Context Menu, then check 'Rename tab'.

I have also used 'Rename Tab Title'. Advantage: You can change the tab title by pressing Ctl-e.

You might want to try both while you wait for Syl to write "Tab Modifier for Firefox"... if only!

Comment: I'm guessing that "Tab Mix Plus" and "'Rename Tab Title" are software. If so, please [edit] your answer to say where they can be obtained.

Comment: Rename Tab Title is a firefox extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rename-tab-title/

Comment: Tab Mix Plus is also a firefox extension but doesn't work with Firefox Quantum and it's unclear whether it ever will.

Comment: Update: Rename Tab Title doesn't work for the stated purpose - it changes the title but Tumblr/Facebook/etc change it back.  Tab Mix Plus used to actually work.

Answer (score 2):

There's a port of the [TabModifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai?hl=en) extension v0.21 to Firefox:

https://github.com/clfer/chrome-tab-modifier/releases/tag/firefox%2F0.21.0

From the archive drag this file onto a FireFox window

```
/dist/web-ext-artifacts/tab_modifier-0.21.0.xpi
```

And install as usual.

It works very well, but it has not been updated since 2018 and for regex **matching** the page title for replacement it uses `g` (`global` modifier) - which makes it quite difficult to create capturing groups.

Answer (score 2):

The tab name of any page is its title.
Changing it is a temporary thing —for the current session only.
As such, I do it with a bookmarklet ... a JavaScript to change the title.

Here it is (make sure it's on one line):

```
javascript:(function()%20{document.title=prompt("Enter%20Page%20Title");})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I made a couple of changes for myself to my preference, doing nothing if the prompt is cancelled (instead of changing to `null`) and setting an interval to refresh the change since the page I'm interested in sets the title back with ajax: `javascript:(function(){if (window.titleIntervalId) clearInterval(window.titleIntervalId);let newTitle = prompt("Enter%20Page%20Title");if (newTitle){window.newTitle = newTitle;document.title = window.newTitle;window.titleIntervalId = setInterval(() => document.title = window.newTitle, 1000);}})();`